# How to set up GitLab CI with a shell runner?

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to set up a minimal working example of GitLab continuous integration. I successfully created a working Spring Boot application and pushed it to my GitLab. I created a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with the simple:

```
run:
  script:
    - ./gradlew bootRun
```

command. And upon pushing my changes I got the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.2 (6d06f2e)
  on Martin-asus-runner (7056052b)
Using Shell executor...
Running on martin-UX305UA...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/7056052b/0/Martin/ci-test'...
Checking out b670a57a as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ ./gradlew bootRun

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Which is strange, since I have Java installed on my computer. After closer examination I found that the GitLab CI has probably created a new user named `gitlab-runner` on my system and that all the CI scripts are executed by this user. Since this user has not installed Java, the environmental variables are not set.

What is the intended way of solving this problem? Can I somehow let the `gitlab-runner` "inherit" my environment?

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @AndrewK sadly, we made a workaround. I just installed docker on the integration  server and then ran explicit `docker run openjdk:latest ./gradlew bootRun` commands in the `script:` section of the `gitlab-ci.yml`. I think that is a better solution, since the official `openjdk` docker container has the environment well configured.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar, I had to run a new server that I could set up to meet the needs of my projects. Good luck with your development!